# Cyclic number field in html

Tags: javascript, numbers, range, cyclic

I want to set my number field in html back to minimum value once the maximum limit is exceeded by incrementing it or the other way.
The field I am currently trying is number with min and max. This does not let the user to increment or decrement beyond the range which does not satisfy my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Try the spinner widget from JQueryUI. The [overflow example](http://jqueryui.com/spinner/) on the website has the following code in the overflow example:

```js
  $( "#spinner" ).spinner({
        spin: function( event, ui ) {
          if ( ui.value > 10 ) {
            $( this ).spinner( "value", -10 );
            return false;
        } else if ( ui.value < -10 ) {
          $( this ).spinner( "value", 10 );
          return false;
        }
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<p>
  <label for="spinner">Select a value:</label>
  <input id="spinner" name="value">
</p>
```

Comment: Any simple way to use with angular by writing some directives etc;